# ModelState.IsValid always true, regardless of DataAnnotations attributes

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, data-annotations

I'm using the new MVC6 framework with Visual Studio 2015, and suddenly all my Data Annotations stopped working. All of them, without me changing the code.

```
public sealed class RegisterUser
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "required")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^((.|\n)*)$", ErrorMessage = "regex")]
    [StringLength(32, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "length")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

And

```
[Route(Address + "/membership")]
public class MembershipController : Controller
{
    // POST [address]/membership/register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("Register")]
    public IActionResult Register([FromBody]RegisterUser model)
    {
        // Validate the input model.
        if (model == null)
            return ...

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return ... 

        // Always get HERE 
    }
}
```

Why, on earth, do I pass the "ModelState.IsValid" test (it always evaluates to true) ?

For example, I'm passing Name="x", and it still evaluates to true. As if the annotations aren't there.

Does it relate to using MvcCore ?

Answer (score 17):

Frustrating as it is, I forgot that changing to 'core' project strips out many of the common features. And so, in Startup.cs, add

- `services.AddMvc()`

or

- `services.AddMvcCore().AddDataAnnotations()`

Depending on your usage.

Answer (score 0):

Was experiencing the same issue and commented this following line of code

```
  services.AddControllersWithViews(options => {
            // options.ModelValidatorProviders.Clear();
        }).AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

I don't remember why I added this line of code...

Answer (score 0):

**{ get; set; } Required**
I know the OP has NOT made this error but I have just wasted a number of hours...

Need to use `public string Name { get; set; }` and not `public string Name;`

I'm using ASP Core 3.1.