# ASP.NET Core and ActionFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, actionfilterattribute

I move old MVC 5 application to Core, old application has code:

```
public class ValidateApiModelStateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var key in actionContext.ModelState.Keys)
            {
                result.Add(key, String.Join(", ", actionContext.ModelState[key].Errors.Select(p => p.ErrorMessage)));
            }
            // 422 Unprocessable Entity Explained
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse<Dictionary<string, string>>((HttpStatusCode)422, result);
        }
    }
}
```

so, it means, that if model state is not valid, then we return dictionary with errors and 422 status code (client's requirements).

I try to rewrite it the following way:

```
[ProducesResponseType(422)]
public class ValidateApiModelStateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var key in context.ModelState.Keys)
            {
                result.Add(key, String.Join(", ", context.ModelState[key].Errors.Select(p => p.ErrorMessage)));
            }

            // 422 Unprocessable Entity Explained
            context.Result = new ActionResult<Dictionary<string, string>>(result);
        }
    }
}
```

but it can't be compiled:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,
>   string>>` to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult`

how to do it?

Comment: If you can use ASP.NET Core 2.1, this is done automatically by the framework

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto my guess would be that they don't want the default 400 response and instead want custom 422 status response.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto what does automatically? I need return exactly this status code with exactly data

Comment: Return new object result and set status code.

Comment: @Nkosi I need exactly 422 status code

Comment: @OlegSh Nkosi is right. Just use ObjectResult instead of using `ActionResult` directly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Contrary to belief [`ActionResult<TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionresult-1?view=aspnetcore-2.1) is not derived from `IActionResult`. Thus the error.

Return new `ObjectResult` and set status code as desired.

```
[ProducesResponseType(422)]
public class ValidateApiModelStateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid) {
            var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var key in context.ModelState.Keys) {
                result.Add(key, String.Join(", ", context.ModelState[key].Errors.Select(p => p.ErrorMessage)));
            }

            // 422 Unprocessable Entity Explained
            context.Result = new ObjectResult(result) { StatusCode = 422 };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason, for me, this does not trigger `context.ModelState.IsValid` to be false even when the properties of the model are null or an empty string. So the 422 result never gets set.

Comment: Update: If anyone else does the foolish mistake I did - I was missing the `AddDataAnnotations()` bit after `services.AddMvcCore()` -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/38963196/413785